# Finding name of a specific problem

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, greedy-algorithms, parallel-computing

Input : $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n \in \mathbb N$.

Output : $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $\sum_{i} a_i b_i=x$ and $\sum_{i}|b_i|$ is minimized.

Main question is, can we solve this problem with greedy or parallel algorithms?

Comment: Often it's more effective to figure out what you want to know about the problem and ask about that.  That way someone might be able to give you a useful answer even if it doesn't have a "name".

Comment: Observe that if $d=\gcd(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$, then we must have that $d$ divides $x$. Otherwise there are is no solution. So, we can write $x=dx'$, $a_i=da_i'$ and cancel $d$ from both sides of the equation to get $\sum_i a_i'b_i=x'$. Now, the equation $\sum_i a_i'b_i=1$ is [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout). A solution of which can be found by repeating [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). You can also describe the structure of the solutions. The wikipedia page mentions the case $n=2$.

Comment: Main question is, can we solve this problem with greedy or parallel algorithms?

Comment: Any constraint on the size of $x$?

Comment: we hove no constraint on $x$